# How to compare (the order) of two bidirectional iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, listiterator

I was wondering if there is a build-in way in C++ to compare the order of two bidirectional iterators. For example, I have a Sum function to calculate the sum between 2 iterators in the same list:

```
double Sum(std::list::const_iterator Start, std::list::const_iterator End){
      double sum=0;
      for (Start;Start!=End;Start++)
           sum+=*Start;
      return sum;
}
```

Then:
`Sum(my_list.begin(),my_list.end());` is fine, but `Sum(my_list.end(),my_list.begin());` will cause runtime error.

I was thinking putting`if (Start>End) return 0;` to prevent the error. But it seems I cannot compare the iterators like this.

Comment: i think that if statement should be a for loop... and if its meant to be a for loop, increasing start++ (when start is actually my_list.end()) will as you expect run out of index.

Comment: There are many [types of iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), not all can support all operations. However, iterators from lists are [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which are a superset of [forward iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) which is a superset of [input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) which support the inequality operator. So you need to elaborate on what your problem is.

Comment: `Sum(my_list.begin(),my_list.end());` This should not compile since it binds temporaries to non-const reference. You most definitely want to drop the `&` in your function definition.

Comment: Also, if you exchange the start and end iterators in the function call, then you need a loop going the other direction instead, which might be the problem you're having.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that is exactly what he is trying to prevent by comparing the iterators

Comment: I really don't think you need to add that protection to your function.  If the user of your code gives you a `start` where `start > end` then that is their problem and the fact the code blows up is a good thing as it will help them to find out where they went wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree. But I want to do something like: `if (Start>end) return 0;`

Comment: You can only do that if you limit the use to [RandomAccessIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [Introduction to the STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html) which explains the various refinements of the Iterator concept.

Only [RandomAccessIterators](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html) support comparison with `<` because it is not an efficient operation for non-RandomAccessIterators.

The only way to tell if a [BidirectionalIterator](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BidirectionalIterator.html) `i` is less-than another, `j`, is by incrementing `i` one step at a time and seeing if you ever reach `j`, but that will never happen if `j` is not reachable from `i`, and is an error if `i` is not incrementable, e.g. because it is the past-the-end iterator for the range.

Alternatively, you could decrement `i` and see if you reach `j`, in which case you know `j` is less-than `i`, but that won't work if `i` is the begin iterator, because you can't iterate before the beginning of the range.

So in general there is no way to know whether one non-RandomAccessIterator comes before or after another, because you can't even know whether to start iterating forwards or backwards to reach the other, and you wouldn't know when it is safe to keep going or when you reach the end of the valid range.

So by convention you always pass the iterators in the same order, so that the begin iterator comes first, and the past-the-end iterator comes second, and the past-the-end iterator can be reached by incrementing the begin iterator zero or more times.

> Then: `Sum(my_list.begin(),my_list.end());` is fine, but `Sum(my_list.end(),my_list.begin());` will cause runtime error.

Don't do that then!

It is the caller's responsibility to call the function correctly, and why would the caller not know which iterator is the start and which is the end?

Answer (score -2):

when you call Sum(my_list.begin(),my_list.end()) , **my_list.begin()** will point to first element in the list

```
double Sum(std::list::const_iterator& Start, std::list::const_iterator& End)
{
      double sum=0;
      if (Start;Start!=End;Start++)
           sum+=*Start;
      return sum;
}
```

SameWay when you call **Sum(my_list.end(),my_list.begin())**,my_list.end() will point to the last element in the list.

Do below changes it will work,

```
    double Sum(std::list<int>::const_iterator Start, std::list<int>::const_iterator End)
{
      double sum=0;
      for (Start;Start!=End;Start)
           sum+=*(--Start);
      return sum;
}
```

Comment: The point is to write the function so that it works for both cases, not just to rewrite it to handle the reverse case.